# How can I go back to the "Table" of a MOre... button in iOS when I click the more button and not the VC I left from

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Navigation controller.

NAVC->MORE... button and then a few extra VCs under the more.

If I go to a VC under the more...and then to one not on the More... then when I return to the More... I go to the VC which I last selected under the More.. and not the actual list for the More...

I was wondering how I can do this.

I have removed the "BACK" buttons from the VCs under the more because it uses up a lot of realestate and the app has a custom header.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the "More" View Controller you can pass it as a reference to the `popToViewController(_:,animated:)` method on UINavigationController:

```
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(MoreViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by reference to the "More" view controller. It is set up by the UINavbarcontroller not sure how to access it.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question then... are you asking how to get back to a view controller other than the one you just left from when using a navigation controller?  Or something else?

Comment: Ok so I have a few Tap Recognizers I can get to difference view controllers using

self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3 etc etc...

It seems that the More.. button once you select a VC on the More list that it sets some property of the actual More button to the selectedIndex of the VC you had previously selected in the More area. I need to hit the "More.." button twice to get to the actual "More list" the moreViewController doesn't have an index like the other buttons on the tab bar to my knowledge.